# Display thumbnailPhoto from Active Directory - Open atrium and LDAP modelude

Tags: authentication-authorization, distributions

I am using Open Atrium for my intranet. I got LDAP module installed, the server is configured, same as User, Authentication, and Authorization.
The communication with my Active Directory is successful, I have all my fields and properties populated correctly, but THUMBNAILPHOTO
[image: Query results]

Do I need to configure something else?? What I am missing? My active Directory uses CodeTwo.

Thanks,

Sofia

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your ldap server

> 1. Go to admin/config/people/ldap/servers
> 2. Click edit
> 3. Go to "LDAP User to Drupal User Relationship" tab
> 4. Under "Thumbnail attribute" add "thumbnailphoto" (without quotes)
> 5. Save your settings

Now your ldap server is configured to automatically copy user thumbnail from ldap (Active Directory) to Drupal.